# How can I determine extremely large prime factors?

Tags: java, primes, long-integer

So I am trying to find an answer to question 3 on project Euler. I need to determine the largest prime factor of a given number.

Quote Project Euler :
"The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.
What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ?"

I have built my code and it works perfectly on anything the size of an int.
But due to the gigantic number they give, my code has conversionproblems.

Originally I tried switching to long variables and long arrays but I get the error :
'possible lossy conversion from long to int'

So how I can I make my code accept extremely long numbers?

```
public class Test {

long[] delers;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test test = new Test();
    test.determineDividers(600851475143,determineNumberOfDividers(600851475143));
    long a = test.determineHighestPrime(test.delers);
    System.out.println(a);
}

public void determineDividers(long getal,long aantalDelers) {
    delers= new long[aantalDelers];
    long k = 0;
    for (long i = 1; i < getal; i++) {
        if (getal % i == 0) {
            delers[k]=i;
            k++;                
        }
    }
}

public long determineNumberOfDividers(long getal) {
    int k = 0;
    for (long i = 1; i < getal; i++) {
        if (getal % i == 0) {
            k++;               
        }
    }
    return k;
}

public boolean determinePrime(long getal) {
    for (long i = 2; i < getal; i++) {
        if (getal % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public long determineHighestPrime(long[] deler) {
    for (long i = deler.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        if (determinePrime(deler[i]) == true) {
            return deler[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

}

Thank you for your time

EDIT 1 : Added example from PE.

EDIT 2 : Added solution

```
public class Test {

long[] delers;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test test = new Test();
    test.determineDividers(600851475143L,test.determineNumberOfDividers(600851475143L));
    long a = test.determineHighestPrime(test.delers);
    System.out.println(a);
}

public void determineDividers(long getal,int aantalDelers) {
    delers= new long[aantalDelers];
    int k = 0;
    for (long i = 1; i < getal; i++) {
        if (getal % i == 0) {
            System.out.println(i);
            delers[k]=i;
            k++;                
        }
    }
}

public int determineNumberOfDividers(long getal) {
    int k = 0;
    for (long i = 1; i < getal; i++) {
        if (getal % i == 0) {
            k++;               
        }
    }
    return k;
}

public boolean determinePrime(long getal) {
    for (long i = 2; i < getal; i++) {
        if (getal % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public long determineHighestPrime(long[] deler) {
    for (int i = deler.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        if (determinePrime(deler[i]) == true) {
            return deler[i];
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

}

Comment: Put an `L` after those huge constants, i.e. `600851475143L`, to tell Java that they have to be `long`.

Comment: What line does the error happen on/around?

Comment: You might consider moving to a `BigDecimal` or `BigInteger` class as well. They are tailored to handle numbers of any size.

Comment: Well i tried putting the 'l' behind the numbers in the main() ,and that removed that error. But i still get these errors on other places in my code. Always when i am trying to manipulate my long[] delers.

Comment: You have to add the `L` to **both** constants.

Comment: "to determine the largest prime factor of a given number" you don't have to store all its prime factors let alone all its divisors so *don't* have to know how many there are of them. -- just use `long`. -- if `n=a*b` and `a` is prime, then prime factorization of `n` is `a` plus the prime factorization of `b = n / a`, right? ... if `n=2*b` and `b` is not divisible by 2,3,4,5,6, but 7 divides it, then `b=7*c` and `c` can *not* be divisible by 2,3,4,5,6 - because else `b` would be. Correct?

Comment: @WillNess Correct, and then I think the largest prime factor of `c` (which could be `c` itself) is also the largest prime factor of `b`, although I don't have a rigorous mathematical proof yet.  This seems like a good approach.

Comment: @ajb right. and again, if `n=a*b` where `a<=b` then `a*a <= a*b = n`, so when we test `c` by `i=7,8,9,...`, when we get to `i` such that `i*i > n`, do we really need to test `c` by `(i+1)` or do we already know at this point that `c` *is* prime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set up an array, the size of the array has to be an `int`.  Therefore, this:

```
delers= new long[aantalDelers];
```

won't compile, because you declared the parameter `aantalDelers` as `long`.  However, when you call `determineDividers`, the value you pass in for `aantalDelers` is the result of `determineNumberOfDividers`, which you declared as returning `long`, but that function says `return k`, and `k` is an `int`.

So I think you can change `determineNumberOfDividers` so that it returns `int` instead of `long`, and change the `aantalDelers` parameter to be `int` instead of `long`.  That way you'll avoid any `long`-to-`int` conversions.  Also, in places where you use `k` and `i` as array indexes, and you declared them as `long`, those should be changed to `int` also.

Off the top of my head, I think this will work because I don't think a number up to 2<sup>63</sup> can have more than 2<sup>31</sup> divisors.  But if my math is wrong and it can, then you'll need some other mechanism besides an array.  (In fact, you may need to come up with another algorithm anyway; I have a feeling that this one is going to take a very long time to run.)

Comment: Reupdated OP.  I still get an error at 'test.determineDividers(600851475143L,test.determineNumberOfDividers(600851475143));' stating : integer number too large 600851475143

Answer (score 1):

Change all the variables that will get "gigantic" to BigInteger.  You'll need to update your Math to use function calls instead of java operands, but they are all available in BigInteger.

Comment: This isn't necessary. 600851475143 is far away from a `long`'s max value of 18446744073709551616.

Comment: Yes. The final question is "So how I can I make my code accept extremely long numbers?".  I figured I'd answer that directly.